# Powershell REST request wont return server response if 404

Tags: json, powershell, httprequest, response

I am still new to Powershell and haven't been able to find anything on this. I am running a REST GET request to a URI which I know for a fact returns a 404 from the server since the resource is not found.

I would like to be able to run a conditional that checks if it's a 404 and skip over it for further processing if this is the case however when I assign the request to a variable, then calling on that later, it just gives me the contents of what my request was. I have never seen anything like this before in other languages...

My basic premise is the following. I first fetch all group names, then loop through that array of names, include the current one in a new URL and make an additional request for that specific group which looks for a SHIFT which will always have the same name. If the group doesn't have that shift by name I want to skip to the next group, otherwise alter some attributes of that newly found shift object.

Here is what my code looks like, as you can see it's not acting correctly

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$user = '******'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString '*******' -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user, $pass
$req  = Invoke-WebRequest -Credential $cred -Uri https://********-np.xmatters.com/api/xm/1/groups
$res  = ConvertFrom-Json $req.Content
$content = $res.data

$base = "https://********-np.xmatters.com/api/xm/1/groups"
$group_name = $content[0].targetName
$path = "$base/$group_name/shifts/MAX-Default Shift"

$shift = Invoke-RestMethod -Credential $cred -Uri $path

Write-Host '-----------------------'
Write-Host $shift
Write-Host '-----------------------'



... RESPONSE BELOW ....



Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
At \\MMFILE\********$\MyDocuments\Group Supers PReliminary.ps1:16 char:10
+ $shift = Invoke-RestMethod -Credential $cred -Uri $path
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

-----------------------
@{id=***********; group=; name=MAX-Default Shift; description="; start=2018-08-21T04:00:00.000Z; end=2018-08-22T04:00:00.000Z; timezone=America/New_York; recurrence=;
 links=}
-----------------------

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

What I would like to do is something like, in shorthand code, `if $shift.code == 404 ... skip ... else ... run additional query`

Comment: Yes, this is an unfortunate reality about the `Invoke-*` web cmdlets.  If you do not get content and instead get a non-success code, they throw an error.

Comment: Any way around this?

Comment: Using `-ErrorAction Stop` to force it into being a terminating error and use a `try/catch` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could suppress the error message via `Try..Catch` and in so doing allow the script to continue:

```
Try {
    $Shift = Invoke-RestMethod http://www.google.com/fakeurl -ErrorAction Stop
    #Do other things here if the URL exists..
} Catch { 
    if ($_.Exception -eq 'The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.') {
       #Do other things here that you want to happen if the URL does not exist..
    }
}
```

Note this will hide all terminating errors from `Invoke-ResetMethod`. You could then use an `if` statement to see if the exception was a 404 and then perform further actions accordingly.

Comment: Yea, but like I said earlier I want to run additional requests, this time a PUT request, but only if the resource exists, so there isn't anything to catch, right? Catching would be if it failed. In that case my other stuff would go in the TRY block, which would break if the request failed.

Comment: Updated my answer. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, things you want to happen if an exception doesn't occur should go in the `Try`. These lines won't be executed when there is a 404 as the code will jump to the `catch` as soon as an exception occurs.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a try ... catch.

```
$code = ""

try{
    $shift = Invoke-RestMethod -Credential $cred -Uri $path
}
catch{
    $code = $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__
}

if($code -eq "404")
{
    continue
    # Other things
}
else
{

    Write-Host '-----------------------'
    Write-Host $shift
    Write-Host '-----------------------'
}
```